# Как правильно спроектировать связи нескольких таблиц?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Добрый день, работаю на фреймворке Yii2, сейчас в кратце объясню суть проблемы.

Мне нужно на страницу вывести 3 вида объектов: это дом, квартивы, коммерция. (естественно некоторые поля у них одинаковые, а некоторые разные). И возникает вопрос, как это реализовать:
1 вариант - создать 1 общую таблицу и по связям каким то образом привязать 3 других таблицы(см домом, квартирами и коммерцией)
2 вариант - создать 3 разных таблицы и выводить их на 1 страницу(но пока что мне это с трудом представляется как это реализовывать)

Кто разбирается в данной теме, прошу высказаться по данному вопросу

вот примерно зрительно как это выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пояснение:
задача: админ может создать 3 вида объектов(аналогия с товарами), у этих объектов имеются общие параметры, такие как например название, стоимость, расположение. Но в зависимости от выбранного объекта (такие как дом, квартира, коммерческое помещение) добавляются дополнительные параметры. Имя в том, что админ выставляет данные объекты на "продажу", а клиенты их покупают(это если не вдаваться в подробности).
И основная проблема у меня возникает, как связать эти дополнительные параметры(у дома это имеющие коммуникации(газ, вода и тд.), у квартиры это количество комнат или прописанные люди, у коммерции это юридический статус).
Если ещё проще говоря, админы продают эти самые места жительства/рабочее место. А клиентам нужно, что бы все виды объектов им высвечивались.

Коммерция - это офисные помещения

Comment: не очень понял а где связи между домами и квартирами , там у таблицы квартиры id_dom например и запросом вытягиваете, или у вас эти вещи никак не связаны? и что тут коммерция что вней находиться какая у нее связь с другими  таблицами?

Comment: Дома это частные дома, они не связаны с квартирами. Я обновил пост

Comment: ну вы можете в каждой таблице добавить поля с параметрами , если у вас таблицы никак не связаны и не будет перекрестных запросов и параметры фиксированные (новых в процессе не будет добавляться или удаляться)

 или можете создать одну таблицу  чисто под параметры и  связать ее  по id дома, квартиры или коммерческого помещения например..

Answer (score -1):

Одну таблицу, разделенную на части. 
В основной части берем сущность, у которой нет связей 1:M, и проходясь по связям записываем связанные с ней элементы в другие части таблицы. Соответственно, сущности никак не связанные с основной отображаться не будут.
Например, таблицы квартира-дом-улица, в которой основная сущность эта квартира могут выглядеть так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]